# Exclude job offers that require me to be a citizen of another country

Tags: support, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

Sometimes I get job offers, just to see, it is not available for my country:

[image: Job offer]

Is it possible, to introduce some field, where a company can restrict the offer to specific country?

As a German, I am really not interested in US-citizen only jobs.

Comment: This would require the system knowing what nationality you are, though - or in some cases, what countries you have a right to work in. That seems like adding a lot of complexity for what is relatively few cases.

Comment: @Pekka웃 [you are not incognito :P](https://imgur.com/a/KCiR3)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, do you mean it would just be adding another field to the ones we already fill in in our profiles?

Comment: I mean the one we already fill in our profiles. I now see you edited your comment. My comment was for the "system is not knowing your nationality" part. Of course this wouldn't be enough if you have permission to work in different countries. But maybe, we could have an option to add additional permissions on our job profile? I am sure, having multiple permission in different countries is not the default case for many users. @Pekka웃

Comment: They totally could do that, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort. I think the problem here is that the job in question requires applicants to have the right to work in the US - but it's a remote job. That *should* be a relatively rare occasion. Most jobs tied to a right to work in a specific country or citizenship (like US gov't jobs) tend to have a physical location, which allows users to filter them out.

Comment: _As a german, I am realy not interested in US-citizen only jobs._ even if you interested, you can't get that job since it is US only

Comment: @i--: Are you sure that US-only means US **citizens** only and not necessarily US **location** only? Those are fundamentally different requirements.

Comment: I think the ambiguity here is very confusing - `Remote [US Only]` - is that: remote but you must live in the US, remote anywhere but you have to be able to work in the US, remote but you must live in the US AND be able to work in the US - this job could actually be anywhere, it doesn't say, the name suggests even Mars!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up; the job has been configured to be displayed across the whole world when it should have been configured to be shown only in the US.

I've notified our support team who will reach out to the employer and make sure they've done the right thing here.

Some of the comments mention that we should have a way to indicate what locations you have the right to work: we already support this in your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current). We assume that you have the right to work in your home location and anything else you have to explicitly indicate whether you require a visa.