# How to exclude US companies from your job search preferencies?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

How to exclude US-based companies from your job search preferences?
How to search only for Europe-based companies jobs?

Most of the offers I am receiving are completely irrelevant for me.

I know I may specify a single country, but I do not want to check all the countries one-by-one. I'd like to click at one button "non-US" only, which *practically* means all the countries I intend, i.e. EU + Schengen + UK.

Comment: Did you already read the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356471/exclude-job-offers-that-require-me-to-be-a-citizen-of-another-country)? Dean Ward's answer indicates that your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) should allow you to indicate in which countries you have the right to work. If you exclude the US, then you shouldn't see jobs from the US (or so goes my reading of his answer).

Comment: @CodyGray See my edit.